# visual studio c++ redis (msopentech port) client , hiredis

Tags: c++, redis, visual-studio-2013, hiredis

I am new to c++, I decided to give it a try visual studio c++, boost, llvm(which already failed with boost 1.55 and visual studio 2013) and redis.

This is a small pet project to parse raw data read from socket and cache into redis.

When I tried to link to hiredis.lib I got lots of errors.

I know I am doing something wrong but my trials turned into endless loop. I anybosy could guide about it , it would be much appreciated.

Kind Regards.

Errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: example4, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  Source.cpp
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dosmap.obj) : error LNK2005: _errno already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: _CrtSetCheckCount already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: _aligned_free already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: _aligned_malloc already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: _calloc_dbg already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(_wctype.obj) : error LNK2005: iswalnum already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(_wctype.obj) : error LNK2005: iswalpha already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(_wctype.obj) : error LNK2005: iswgraph already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(_wctype.obj) : error LNK2005: iswspace already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(mlock.obj) : error LNK2005: _lock already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(mlock.obj) : error LNK2005: _unlock already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(winapisupp.obj) : error LNK2005: __crtCaptureCurrentContext already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(winapisupp.obj) : error LNK2005: __crtCapturePreviousContext already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(winapisupp.obj) : error LNK2005: __crtSetUnhandledExceptionFilter already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(winapisupp.obj) : error LNK2005: __crtTerminateProcess already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(winapisupp.obj) : error LNK2005: __crtUnhandledException already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(tidtable.obj) : error LNK2005: _getptd already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: _invalid_parameter already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(sprintf.obj) : error LNK2005: sprintf already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbghook.obj) : error LNK2005: __crt_debugger_hook already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(_file.obj) : error LNK2005: __iob_func already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(_file.obj) : error LNK2005: _lock_file already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(_file.obj) : error LNK2005: _unlock_file already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: _amsg_exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: _cexit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: _exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: _initterm_e already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(errmode.obj) : error LNK2005: __set_app_type already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(winxfltr.obj) : error LNK2005: _XcptFilter already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(wsetloca.obj) : error LNK2005: _configthreadlocale already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(vsnprnc.obj) : error LNK2005: vsprintf_s already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(fflush.obj) : error LNK2005: fflush already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(hooks.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl terminate(void)" (?terminate@@YAXXZ) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: __xi_a already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: __xi_z already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: __xc_a already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: __xc_z already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgrptw.obj) : error LNK2005: _CrtDbgReportW already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(printf.obj) : error LNK2005: printf already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll) : error LNK2005: strcpy_s already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(strcpy_s.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll) : error LNK2005: iswdigit already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(_wctype.obj)
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>hiredis.lib(hiredis.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol strerror_r referenced in function __redisSetError
1>hiredis.lib(net.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol strerror_r
1>hiredis.lib(hiredis.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol fdapi_close
1>hiredis.lib(net.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol fdapi_close
1>hiredis.lib(net.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol fcntl
1>hiredis.lib(net.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol poll
1>F:\SoftwareDevelopment\cplusplus\example4\x64\Debug\example4.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Project File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{FADCAD1B-D309-427E-8A12-2140E0CC1E3C}</ProjectGuid>
    <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
    <RootNamespace>example4</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v120</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v120</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v120</PlatformToolset>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v120</PlatformToolset>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'" Label="PropertySheets">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'" Label="PropertySheets">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>false</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <LinkIncremental>false</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>NotUsing</PrecompiledHeader>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;_LIB;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>F:\Software\boost_1_55_0;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <DebugInformationFormat>None</DebugInformationFormat>
      <MultiProcessorCompilation>true</MultiProcessorCompilation>
      <MinimalRebuild>false</MinimalRebuild>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>F:\Software\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <AdditionalDependencies>%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
    </Link>
    <PostBuildEvent>
      <Command>copy *.config "$(TargetDir)*.config"</Command>
    </PostBuildEvent>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>NotUsing</PrecompiledHeader>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;_LIB;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>F:\Software\boost_1_55_0;F:\Software\redis\deps\hiredis;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <DebugInformationFormat>None</DebugInformationFormat>
      <MultiProcessorCompilation>true</MultiProcessorCompilation>
      <MinimalRebuild>false</MinimalRebuild>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>F:\Software\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <AdditionalDependencies>%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
    </Link>
    <PostBuildEvent>
      <Command>copy *.config "$(TargetDir)*.config"</Command>
    </PostBuildEvent>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <PrecompiledHeader>
      </PrecompiledHeader>
      <Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>
      <FunctionLevelLinking>true</FunctionLevelLinking>
      <IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;NDEBUG;_CONSOLE;_LIB;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <PrecompiledHeader>
      </PrecompiledHeader>
      <Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>
      <FunctionLevelLinking>true</FunctionLevelLinking>
      <IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;NDEBUG;_CONSOLE;_LIB;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="app.config" />
    <None Include="log.config">
      <DeploymentContent>true</DeploymentContent>
      <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
      </ExcludedFromBuild>
      <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
      </ExcludedFromBuild>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="Source.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\..\Software\redis\msvs\hiredis\hiredis.vcxproj">
      <Project>{13e85053-54b3-487b-8ddb-3430b1c1b3bf}</Project>
      <Private>true</Private>
      <ReferenceOutputAssembly>true</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
      <CopyLocalSatelliteAssemblies>false</CopyLocalSatelliteAssemblies>
      <LinkLibraryDependencies>true</LinkLibraryDependencies>
      <UseLibraryDependencyInputs>false</UseLibraryDependencyInputs>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets" />
</Project>
```

Answer (score 2):

When building an executable that uses hiredis, make sure you link to *both* `hiredis.lib` and `Win32_Interop.lib` under

```
Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies
```

Also, you might want to change the runtime library to dll versions (`Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)`) for all projects that you are building

```
Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime-Library
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to link against `hiredis.lib` AND `Win32_Interop.lib`.

The errors you see are because the `hiredis.lib` you use is build with (Multi-threaded(/MT)) and your executable uses the /MD runtime-library.

You can can change it under

```
Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime-Library
```

Download the source code from https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis
and rebuild `hiredis.lib` and `Win32_Interop.lib` with /MD flag and the correct plattform (either Win32 or x64).
Both projects are in the `/msvc/RedisServer.sln`.

Answer (score 0):

First, set Project Property

## 1

Project > Property > Configuration Properties

> General > Project Defaults > Charset
> Use Multi-Byte Character Set

## 2

> C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library
> Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)

and then try to complie your project...

new error appear like beyond)

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(376,5): error MSB8031: Building an MFC project for a non-Unicode character set is deprecated. You must change the project property to Unicode or download an additional library. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=286820 for more information.

you must download "MFC MBCS DLL"

I try to resolve this problem, and downloading and install this file...